# Postgres in Docker; two instances clashing ports

Tags: postgresql, docker, port

I've created a docker container which hosts a postgres server.  I'm trying to get two instances of this running which index two completely different databases, and thus rely on a different set of volumes.

I'm running the following two commands one after the other:

```
docker run -v ... -p 5432:9001 -P --name psql-data postgres-docker
docker run -v ... -p 5432:9002 -P --name psql-transactions postgres-docker
```

The first container is created and runs, but the second call throws the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint psql-transactions on network bridge: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed.  Port already in use.
```

I'm finding this a little confusing, because I though the point of containers was to isolate port binding.  I could understand if I'd had both containers map 5432 onto the same port on the host machine, but I'm trying to mount them to 9001 and 9002 respectively.

How do I prevent this issue?

Comment: Do you need to expose and remap the port? You can access them by hostname when you link containers

Comment: The first port published is on the host, so obviously you have to change one of the two

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to access the ports from external-non docker places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the ports should be reversed. It should be `-p host_port:container_port`

Answer (score 5):

First of all, only publish (`-p`) ports if you need to access them from outside the Docker host; if the database is only used by other services running in a container, there's no need to publish the ports; containers can access the database through the docker network.

If you intend to access the database externally, you need to swap the order of the ports in your `-p`; `-p <host-port>:<container-port>`. So in your case;

```
docker run -v ... -p 9001:5432-P --name psql-data postgres-docker
docker run -v ... -p 9002:5432 -P --name psql-transactions postgres-docker
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the port clash you need to run it like this:

```
docker run -v ... -p 9001:5432 -P --name psql-data postgres-docker
docker run -v ... -p 9002:5432 -P --name psql-transactions postgres-docker
```